# Most Secure Workflow for encrytion of data on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, devise

Hi I working on a rails app that will store sensitive medical records, therefore I have been looking the best practice methods to encrypt stored data. I have decided to use the gem strongbox that provides symmetric encryption by generating a random key and IVs followed by the encryption of those with a public key. The application will need to provide access to encrypted data to both the user and also a series of Special Users(registered medical doctors).

My question relates to the fact that I need the workflow to have two properties that I'm not too sure how to implement:

**1st** problem is that I would like to use the password for the user that is logged in and submitting the data, as the public key, but I'm using the gem Devise that stores encrypted passwords. I don't want to use the encrypted password since if someone is able to access the database it can defeat the encryption workflow.

**2nd** the second problem is that the encrypted information also needs to be accessed not only by the user that created the information but also by a series of special users (medical users). I know that PHP has a function openssl_seal that can take an array of public keys but I'm not sure about the implementation:

do I need to encrypt and store the symmetric key for each recipient public key ? 
or can I just provide all the public keys and us that to encrypt and store that once

**3rd** problem is combination of the first and second, how do I have access to the public keys for the multiple recipients without storing anything on the server that could compromise the workflow security?

What I'm kind of looking for is some advise and discussion regarding the overview of the architecture rather then the practical(code) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the password or even encrypted password as the public key is a bad idea because if their password changes, so does you'r "public key". Instead, I would build an extra field for the user `api_key` or `public_key` (you get the idea). When the user is created, generate the public key.

> ```
>  before_create :new_user_settings
>  def new_user_settings
>     begin
>       self.api_key = SecureRandom.hex
>     end while self.class.exists?(api_key: api_key)
>   end
> ```

This kind of answers your second and third issue as you have a public key in the user model that can decrypt the data. One thing that you can do to help protect against someone who may gain access to your database is to combine the user's public key with another public key. This way the user's public key is only a partial public key and the other half is never stored in the database, but rather as a global variable (or something). The two halves combined will be the actual public key used to decrypt the data.

Comment: That seems appropriate to add a user_api_key due to password changes, although using a global variable still leaves hole in the workflow if both the server and the database are compromised(they will probably be on the same server). My ultimate goal is to find a solution that even in case of a breach the data would still be safe.